# Incrementing numbers

Tags: java, swing, timer, mouselistener

- I have a variable value which tracks whether the number is odd or even.
- I intialized a `int value = 0;`
- The variable "value" is now 0, After clicking 2 times, the system will print out "even" and after one second, the variable "value" will be incremented by 1;
- The variable "value" is now 1, it's odd number so it will print out, "odd" and after one second, the variable value will be incremented by 1;
- The variable "value" is now 2, it's even number so it will again allow the user to onClick on the JFrame 2 times. After clicking 2 times, the system will print out "even" and after one second, the 
  variable "value" will be incremented by 1;
- The variable "value" is now 3, it's odd number so it will print out, "odd" and after one second, the variable value will be incremented by 1;

  and so on...

This goes on until I close the program.

---

I placed the "value" inside my timer and increment it but however the "value" is not incrementing after the countdown. why is it not incrementing? please help.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial") 
public class OnClickLesson extends JFrame   {

    private int value = 0, clicked = 0, countdown = 1;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, null);
    public OnClickLesson() {
        timer = new Timer(1000, new countDownTimer());  

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {        
                if(value%2 == 0) {
                    clicked++;
                    if(clicked == 2) {
                        System.out.println("even");
                        timer.start();      
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        if(value%2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("odd");
            timer.start();          
        }

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setSize(400,600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class countDownTimer implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (countdown == 0) {
                timer.stop();   
                countdown = 1;
                value++;
            }           

            else {
                System.out.println("Countdown " + countdown--);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new OnClickLesson();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: From my test, when I double click the frame, the timer is started, it counts down and increments `value` and sets `countdown` to `1`.  At this point it's impossible to restart the timer because value is now odd...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've made a small logical error in your code...

If you take a look at this section...

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {        
        if(value%2 == 0) {
            clicked++;
            if(clicked == 2) {
                System.out.println("even");
                timer.start();      
            }
        }
    }
});

if(value%2 == 1) {
    System.out.println("odd");
    timer.start();          
}
```

I believe the `if(value%2 == 1) {...` statement is suppose to be inside the `mousePressed` method...

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {        
        if(value%2 == 0) {
            clicked++;
            if(clicked == 2) {
                System.out.println("even");
                timer.start();      
            }
        } else if(value%2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("odd");
            timer.start();          
        }
    }
});
```

This way, when the `mousePressed` is called, it can equally evaluate both states.

Also, I think you should probably reset the `clicked` value

```
clicked++;
if(clicked == 2) {
    System.out.println("even");
    timer.start();      
    clicked = 0;
}
```

Otherwise you will never be able to trigger the `"even"` section again...